# Start and stop a service using BroadcastReceivers in Android

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have a service in my application which I want to run in a specified time period. I am using AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver to start my service let's say at ***startTime***. Now I want to stop the service at ***endTime***. Please help me on how to achieve this. From following some posts I understand that this can be done with IntentFilters but how to use those in this case? Also, is it okay to use static variable in BroadcastReceiver to keep track of number of calls to startService/stopService?